# Enforcing ssl for certain site but not for an other one

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ssl, iis-7

I have a site and a test version of the site hosted on the same server. I want the live version to use ssl but not not the test version. I use the following code to enforce SSL for live and not for test:

```
 If HttpContext.Current.Request.IsSecureConnection.Equals(False) AndAlso HttpContext.Current.Request.IsLocal.Equals(False) AndAlso HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl.Contains("test.mydomain.com") = False Then

            Response.Redirect("https://" + Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_HOST") + HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl)
        End If
```

The live version of the site is **live.mydomain.com**.

The result i get is that any request to **test.mydomain.com** goes to **live.mydomain.com**. I have no idea how this is possible. The browser actually displays **test.mydomain.com** in the address field but is clearly using the live version. There is no SSL binding for **test.mydomain.com**. I have spent several days on this and was wondering if someone knew what is wrong with my code or what else i may try.

many thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in IIS (without any code in your application) by rewriting the URL using the [IIS7 URL Rewrite module](http://www.iis.net/extensions/URLRewrite).

This is a really useful resource for this kind of thing: http://ruslany.net/2009/04/10-url-rewriting-tips-and-tricks/

What you want to do is a combination of (3) and (4).

So it says IF the request is NOT coming in on HTTPS AND the hostname is live.domain.com THEN redirect to HTTPS.

Something like this:

```
<rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" negate="true" pattern="live\.mydomain\.com$" /> 
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Hi Dommer, this looks like the better way of doing it. I will test it shortly and report back. I have a question though: I do not want to use ssl for local developement. Where in the rules is that taken care of? Many thanks M

Comment: In the rule it will redirect ONLY if the URL is `live.mydomain.com` - if I have written it correctly ;-). Even if I have made a mistake, this should be enough for you to work it out yourself. I guess when you are doing local development it would be `localhost` wouldn't it?